# Same hash value but not same object after overriding __hash__

Tags: python, hash, overriding

I'm having a problem correctly hashing my objects.  Consider the following code:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.keys = list(bar.keys())
        self.values = list(bar.values())    
    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join( '%s: %s' % z for z in zip(self.keys, self.values))    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = set()
    d = { 1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8 }
    for i in range(10):
        result.add(Foo(d))
    for r in result:
        print r, hash(r)
```

I expect the result set to contain a single element, since all the added `Foo` objects have the same contents, and therefore the same hash.

However, this is the result:

```
misha@misha-K42Jr:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python hashproblem.py 
1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8 2131119371379196338
1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8 2131119371379196338
1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8 2131119371379196338
1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8 2131119371379196338
1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8 2131119371379196338
1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8 2131119371379196338
1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8 2131119371379196338
1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8 2131119371379196338
1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8 2131119371379196338
1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6, 7: 8 2131119371379196338
```

What is the problem here?  The hashes **do** look the same, so shouldn't they be treated as duplicates by the built-in `set` object?  Why does the set contain duplicates?

I've noticed that if I use `str(Foo(d))` instead of `Foo(d)` when adding elements to the set, things work as expected.  Why does it matter?

Python version is:

```
misha@misha-K42Jr:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `__hash__` method is only use for the internal hash-table, you need to redefine `__eq__` as well.

Overriding only `__eq__` is not correct either. If two object are equal, ie, `a.__eq__(b) == True`, then both `hash(a)` and `hash(b)` must be equal as well.

The default `__hash__` method is:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return id(self)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to work.  Do I need to bother overriding `__hash__`, or is `__eq__` sufficient?

Comment: @misha, the default `__hash__` of an object is to `return id(self)`. It is not strictly needed an override.

Comment: I think implementing `__eq__` but not implementing `__hash__` would break this example.  `Foo(d)` is creating 10 new `Foo` instances.  Presumably the `dict` implementation only looks for equal keys in the same hash bucket.

Comment: @Mikel, I stand corrected. If a.__eq__(b) == True then hash(a) should equal hash(b).

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it out: if you don't override `__hash__`, you get `TypeError: unhashable instance`

Answer (score 4):

See: http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable - you'll want to implement `__eq__` as well.